# Extended Huffman Coding

Tags: huffman-code

I know this is not a coding issue but since I found some Huffman questions here I am posting here since I still need this for my implementation. When doing extended Huffman coding, I understand that you do for example a1a1,a1a2,a1a3 etc and you do their probabilities times, however, how do you get the codeword? For example from the image below how do you get that 0.6400 = 0 and 0.0160 = 10101, etc?[image]

Comment: Some **code** would be nice here. Stack Overflow is not for theory questions. The important question is: *What have you tried*?

Comment: everything is working with the code but I need to find a way to produce the codeword, which I cannot code if I do not understand it theoretically

Comment: **What code**? You can't expect us to know what you've done. The Stack Overflow method is pretty simple: Post code you've created that has a problem you can describe and people will guide you towards a solution. If you post nothing, you'll get nothing.

Comment: @tadman This isn't a question that goes on the CS Theory Stackexchange site though.  I feel like it was a reasonable question, as writing code before you understand something is a terrible idea, and I think your insistence on getting code first is not helpful.

Comment: @TheoBelaire Generally I agree with you, but in this case it would help considerably to know about the target language. Isn't it a good idea to try something first, no matter how ham-fisted it might be, and then seek advice on how to fix it if you encounter a specific problem? If someone's at a complete loss, a quick stop at the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) is always a great place to start. Questions where someone needs advice on how to fill in a gap in their knowledge is a lot better than something as wildly open-ended as this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let me describe how a Huffman tree works, then I will explain how extended Huffman encoding works.

Some terms, `codeword` means a sequence of bits in our encoded output, that has been compressed.
Terms like a1, a2 or a3 are our input characters, we can think of them as letters for now.

We have the two rules,

1. More common letters map to shorter code words than less likely to appear letters.
2. The two least likely letters have the same length code word.

These two requirements lead to a simple way of building a binary
tree describing an optimum prefix code - THE Huffman Code.

Start with the two most unlikely letters, we know their codewords will be `p0` and `p1` for some prefix `p`, now we merge them and consider them as one super-letter, and find the two least common
letters again.

Repeat until the prefix is empty.

Right, now for the extended code, we just group a sequence of letters, pairs in your example, and treat them as one letter in a much larger alphabet.

Source: http://www.ws.binghamton.edu/fowler/fowler%20personal%20page/EE523_files/Ch_03%20Huffman%20&%20Extended%20Huffman%20%28PPT%29.pdf

Comment: yes yes I know how Huffman works but I cannot understand how you get out the code word for extended huffman

Comment: _The same way._  You now have nine symbols instead of three.  Apply Huffman's algorithm to code the nine symbols with those nine probabilities.